# Why there are no fully articulated 2 rotoblades helicopter

Tags: aircraft-design

Why can't R22 and R44 make the 2 rotoblades fully articulated
Like cabri G2 helicopter but only 2 blades
So that easier to store in the hanger than 3 blades rotor blades helicopter and no mast bumping problem like semi rigid R44 mast bumping problem

Comment: I do not know for sure but my suspicion is this…  You get a lot of simplicity out of a rigid rotor, and a lower cost to build, maintain, and replace.  I think that once your design criteria moves up into the domain of fully articulated hubs, then you are also in a design and mission space that benefits from multiple blades.  So I think that it’s not “two-blade tutors have rigid hubs” but rather, “articulated hubs tend to have more blades.”